# Creating hit Counter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to create a hit counter for my website and I have developed the following code for it. I have included the following code only in Codeigniter's main controller for my home page.

At first I thought the code was working fine but I just found that if I don't keep on browsing the pages then again go to the home page it doesn't update the data. I mean for example: If I go to my homepage for the first time then it updates the data, but after 10 seconds if I refresh the page it does't update the data. But if I keep refreshing it for 10 seconds then it works.

So could you please tell me how to get it update the data without having to keep on browsing the pages or refreshing the home page?

Thanks :)

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    // Visitor Counter
    if (!$this->session->userdata('timeout')) {

        $out = time() + 10; // I will change it to $out = time() + 60*60; later 
        $this->session->set_userdata('timeout', $out);
        mysql_query("UPDATE cane_visitor_counter SET visitor_stat = visitor_stat+1 
              WHERE id = '1'");
    } else {
        $timeout_time = $this->session->userdata('timeout');
        if (time() > $timeout_time) {

            $this->session->set_userdata(array('timeout' => ''));
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

### edit

What I am trying to achieve is when an user visits the webpage for the first time, I want to update my database. Within 10 seconds (for example purpose), if the visitor again visits the home page, the database will not be updated. But after 10 seconds if he again visits the home page, I want to update my database.

Thanks :)

Comment: That's not a visitor counter, that's a hit counter

Comment: Yes Your right. I am updating my question

Comment: @black_belt - so do you want it to update every time it's called? Because all you have to do then is remove the timeout code.

Comment: CodeIgniter provides a DBMS-independent query system, and `mysql_*` is deprecated anyways.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Why not just use Google Analytics or something?

Comment: Just to jump on the bandwagon of criticizing the database access, you don't put single quotes around numeric values either.

Comment: how far along are u on this? I mean just to pass it on you shouldnt be using mysql_ try mysqli_ or my favourite: PDO, mysql_ is gonna be deprecated sooner than later

Comment: @MuqMan Surely that didn't take you 4 minutes to write, so you knew that exact comment has already been made twice. The "it's gonna be deprecated" argument is the weakest you can give as well; it'll still be in PHP v.Current 10 years from now. Talk about prepared statements or something.

Comment: Lol, sorry didnt read the others

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply. And thanks to Matt, MuqMan and Dan Grossman for pointing out my mistake in mysql_* function. I will probably be using the codeigniter way of quering.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am already using the Google analytic but I cannot show the hit counter in my webpage using it.

Comment: Just so you know, that sort of became passé in the late 1990s...

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes I know, but that's what I was asked to implement :(

Comment: There are lots of visible hit counters you can just copy and paste into a page. Like http://www.w3counter.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says "if there is no timeout in the session, update the count". You want it to say "if there is no timeout in the session, or there is but it's old, update the count".

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    // Visitor Counter
    if (!$this->session->userdata('timeout') || $this->session->userdata('timeout') < time()) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('timeout', time() + 10);
        mysql_query("UPDATE cane_visitor_counter SET visitor_stat = visitor_stat + 1 WHERE id = 1");
    }

}
```

I'm not a CodeIgniter user, so I am assuming that you used its session facilities correctly; I just used them the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your code and I think its working the way I wanted. Thanks :) I guess I just now have to change the way of querying. Thanks